# Can I apply the properties of the inner product to the operations related to the gradient?

Tags: linear-algebra, gradient-descent

I would like to know if it is true that $\nabla\cdot A = A ⋅\nabla$, where $A$ is a vector field.

Comment: If you defined $\nabla$ appropriately, this should be okay.

Comment: What would $A \cdot \nabla$ mean?

Comment: I don't think so; the first is a scalar field, the second is an operator sending tensor fields to tensor fields, and I don't see a way to get from one to the other in a canonical way in this case.

Comment: mas existe a operação A⋅∇ ???
teria alguma referencia em literatura para visualização? procurei em livros e sempre aparece apenas forma ∇⋅A,